# Could NuGet be used in Non-Software Development area?

Tags: nuget

I know the NuGet, is primarily targeting software development, but I see potential other uses.

For example;-
 a simple Document Control System. (I can't see office workers figuring out a full blow CVS)
  One person creates the new version, and that is automatically published to document repository.

eg The latest version of Health & Safety documentation is being used.
 or The latest version of the Expenses Claims Form.

Are there other potential uses?

Answer (score 1):

NuGet isn't a versioning system, it's a distribution system.  The only thing I can see it being useful for in document management is distributing document templates. You're much better off using something like SharePoint, a shared folder, or even a url to a website to ensure that everyone is using the correct version of a shared document.

However, NuGet has certainly been picked up by a few people although not outside the software development community that I have seen.  I believe it plays a core part (or did at one stage) of PsGet, Chocolatey, TfsGet and Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using NuGet would be any more friendly than using a VCS. Both of them are command-based, but could be wrapped in a UI. In fact, using something like TortoiseHG with Mercurial would probably be easier than NuGet, since there isn't currently any UI for NuGet outside of Visual Studio?